# Is 「学生時代の友人」grammatical?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 学生時代からの友人というのは、いいものだ。
>
> > Book translation: old friends from one's schooldays are great.

I wonder, however, if 学生時代の友人 is possible. If so, I think the difference between both would be that the former implies that you're still friends with them while, in the latter, there's no such implication: "Friends **of** college days."

Comment: You have just beautifully answered your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I feel you didn't meet the friend for a few years when you say 「学生時代の友人」.

「学生時代からの友人」sounds like you still keep in touch with the friend from college days.